# Why is the list not getting appended at each iteration of the `for` loop?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

The `X_next` is getting updated in each iteration, but although I do the `XList.append(X_next)` at each iteration, only `X_next` computed in the *last* iteration is getting appended at each iteration. You can see this as I'm printing them `X_next` at each iteration and `XList` after the `for` loop.

**Code:**

```
import pylab as pl

def acc(x):
    return -1 - x

X_prev = pl.array([1, 0])
X_next = pl.array([0., 0])
dt = 0.1

XList =[]

for i in range(0, 10):
    x1 = X_prev[0] + X_prev[1]*dt/2
    X_next[1] = X_prev[1] + acc(x1)*dt
    X_next[0] = x1 + X_next[1]*dt/2
    print(X_next)
    XList.append(X_next)
    X_prev = X_next

print(XList)
```

**Result:**

```
[ 0.99 -0.2 ]
[ 0.9601 -0.398 ]
[ 0.910599 -0.59202 ]
[ 0.84199201 -0.7801198 ]
[ 0.7549651 -0.9604184]
[ 0.65038854 -1.13111282]
[ 0.52930809 -1.29049611]
[ 0.39293456 -1.43697444]
[ 0.24263169 -1.56908302]
[ 0.0799025  -1.68550078]
[array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078]), array([ 0.0799025 , -1.68550078])]
```

---

**Question:** Why is this so and how to solve this?

Comment: you need to append a copy of the list, right now you are appending a pointer to the list

Comment: You have one array called `X_next` that you are modifying and repeatedly appending to your list. So you end up with a list containing the same array lots of times.

Comment: @khelwood But `X_next` is getting modified at each iteration, and *that* modified value is appended to `XList`. Then where is the problem?

Comment: @depperm Can you please elaborate?

Comment: append a copy of `X_next` or have `X_next = pl.array([0., 0])` within the for loop and you're problem will be solved

Comment: @Atom It's not the _value_ that gets appended to the list. It's the _object_ held at `X_next` that you're appending over and over again.

Comment: @khelwood And that updates the values of `X_next` within the `XList` over and over again. Thanks!